# Multistability in the lactose ultization network

Tags: bioinformatics, computational-model

Reading the paper [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v427/n6976/abs/nature02298.html), I'm confused about the production of figure 4d. The method of production is detailed in the [supplementary information](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v427/n6976/suppinfo/nature02298.html) under the heading "Theoretical phase diagram".

Specifically, I'm confused about the use of theta and what it means. I have tried reproducing the figure using MATLAB and the parameters in the paper to see whether I can understand it better, but nothing quite works out.

To be clear, the paper obtains a steady state result for a series of ODEs: 
$$
    y = \frac{\alpha  (1+(βy)^2)}{ρ+(βy)^2}
$$
Then rearranges as a cubic: 
$$
    y^3 −αy^2 + \frac{ρ}{ β^2} y − \frac{α }{ β^2 } = 0 
$$
Apparently, a general cubic with two identical roots has the
form:
$$
    (y-a)(y-a)(y-aθ) = y^3 - (2 + θ)ay^2 + (1+2θ)a^2 y - θa^3
$$
The paper then equates coefficients:
\begin{align}
    ρ &= (1 + 2θ)(1 + 2/θ)\\
    aβ &= \frac{(2 + θ)^{3/2}}{θ^{1/2}}\tag{did you mean?}
\end{align}
And claims that these are the parametric equations that describe the graph in question. When plotting these equations, I get nothing like the graph. I can't really see where it comes from.

The graph in question and some equations are reproduced here on the last page:
http:// web.mit.edu/biophysics/sbio/PDFs/L7_notes.pdf

Comment: I don't have access to nature so I have no idea what the figure looks like. You need to post the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation in the OP has been updated to $(y-a)^2(y-a\theta)$ which yields the correct expansion. Therefore, by equating the coefficients, we obtain
\begin{align}
\alpha &= (2+\theta)a\tag{1}\\
\rho/\beta^2 &= a^2(1+2\theta)\tag{2}\\
\alpha/\beta^2 &= a^3\theta\tag{3}
\end{align}
Using equations (1) to (3), we get the desired $\rho$ and $\alpha\beta$. Now the authors plotted $\frac{\alpha\beta}{\rho}$ and $\frac{1}{\rho}$.

By plotting $\frac{\alpha\beta}{\rho}$ and $\frac{1}{\rho}$, we can re-create the plot in Mathematica with

```
ParametricPlot[{1/((1 + 2 x) (1 + 2/x)), (2 + x)^(3/2)/(
  Sqrt[x] (1 + 2 x) (1 + 2/x))}, {x, 0.01, 50 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, .15}, {0, 0.6}}, AspectRatio -> 3/4]
```

[image]

If you dont have Mathematica, here is some Python code that will plot it as well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
t = np.linspace(0.01, 25*np.pi, 5000)
x = 1/((1+2*t)*(1+2/t))
y = (2+t)**1.5/(np.sqrt(t)*(1+2*t)*(1+2/t))
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Here is the Python plot which has smoother lines compared to Mathematica's plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought something was up... Assuming their maths had been correct and the equations for rho and alpha-beta were correct, how would you go about using them? I'm a little confused about the theta?

Comment: The plot on the last page of http://web.mit.edu/biophysics/sbio/PDFs/L7_notes.pdf

Comment: Sorry could you please add a link to the wolfram alpha graph?

Comment: @user2290362 I plotted it in Python since Wolfram will only plot it if you have the full version of Mathematica.